# Ajax post in mvc returns no success

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, post, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have written an Ajax POST to submit a form, but it fails to succeed.

The Ajax POST comes through to the action in the controller which in turn will return a PartialView, which is also made correctly as I can debug this.

The goal is to let the user add a new log, whatever the outcome (failed captcha, failed validation) a Partialview will be returned with the right ViewBag errors messages. Razor takes care of the rest. This way the user will not be redirected to other pages.

When the Ajax succeeds it should put the data in the right `<div>`. The code is a copy of a working Ajax GET only changing it into a POST and providing the formdate serialized.

tldr; Ajax POST to Action in controller works, the partialview is rendered and returned yet the Ajax failes to succeed making it unable to update the designated `<div>`

Ajax call:

```
<script>
$('#add-log').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: $('#add-log').attr('data-url'),
        type: 'post',
        data: $("#log-form").serialize(),
        succes: function (data) {
            $('#add-log').attr('data-target').html(data);
            console.log("Succes");
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
[Authorize(Roles = "Student")]
public ActionResult Add(object sender, Log log, string returnURL, bool SendEmail)
{
        ViewBag.Vulns = TempData["Vulns"];

        //region Captcha: Here we have our Captcha settings
        var response = Request["g-recaptcha-response"];
        //secret that was generated in key value pair
        const string secret = "Just a secret for our captcha, move along";

        var client = new WebClient();
        var reply = client.DownloadString(string.Format("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={0}&response={1}", secret, response));
        var captchaResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CaptchaResponse>(reply);

        if (ModelState.IsValid && captchaResponse.Success)
        {
            db.Log.Add(log);
            db.SaveChanges();

            if (SendEmail)
            {
            //Emails are sent from here on out, but that's out of the scope
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!captchaResponse.Success)
            {
                ViewBag.fillcaptcha = "Please fill in the captcha";
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Wrong = "Something went wrong please try again";
            }
            ViewBag.returnUrl = returnURL;
            ViewBag.domain = log.DomainId;
            return PartialView(log);
        }
}
```

There's more code but I left that out. Most important thing in the controller is just the last IF. I test the ajax by posting an empty log with no captcha resulting in a partialview with the same log and the viewbag.captcha error. This partialview is rendered but somehow ajax doesn't succeed.

Comment: You've said that the AJAX POST works, *and* that it fails.  Which is it?  If it's working, then how exactly is it failing?

Comment: You have a typo in your JavaScript code.  The callback function property should be called `success`.  Basically you don't have a "success" callback, so your code is simply ignoring the AJAX response.

Comment: @David what I meant is that the AJAX POST succeeds to call the action in the controller with the right data.

Comment: Well this is embarrassing, that explains all the frustration. You've got to love the error handling when using javascript. Ok, thank you for reviewing the code.